# Google maps API v3 - How are client loads detected?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a small and low key website what features Google Maps using the v3 Javascript API.

Not that I am expecting to get over 25,000 loads per day, but how does Google detect people loading the map on my site? My site uses the the following code `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` without any API key, and as it is rendered in the clients browser, how does Google relate it to my site?

Is the loads worked out through the http headers/referrers or are the loads based on how many times each client/IP loads the map?

In essence, the code for the map is rendered on my clients/users browsers and thus how do Google know how many people are using the map on my site?

Finally; although I have Google web master tools; is it worth creating & using a API key, or will it just make it possible for Google to track how many people are using the map on my site and thus apply the limit of 25,000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API sends a request to google which contains the URI of the page that contains the map(when you inspect the network-traffic inside the dev-tools you'll see a request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent ) . This request will be sended when a Maps-instance has been created successfully.

The benefit of using a key: google is able to contact you when there are issues(e.g. may send a notice when you have reached any limits and give you a chance to react/solve the issue before they restrict the API-access for your domain/account).

Comment: Also a friend told me it is the tiles (what are normally stitched together) that load on the map what count towards the limit and not just loading the map up it's self. Is this true?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter how many tiles will be loaded by the client. When you have a single map on a page each time you load the page(and the map) it will count as 1 map-load, no matter what the user will do with the map(except requesting services like e.g.  geocoding or directions, which have separate quotas) . When you have a single page with two maps it will count as 2 map-loads.